# Having valid SRIDs issue with SDO_GEOM.SDO_LENGTH in Oracle Spatial

Tags: oracle, oracle-spatial

When checking geometry object like this

```
SELECT t.STREET_ID,
t.FC_GEOM.SDO_SRID SRID,
SUBSTR(t.FC_GEOM.SDO_GTYPE, 1, 1) DIM_COUNT,
SUBSTR(t.FC_GEOM.SDO_GTYPE, 4, 1) GTYPE,
SDO_GEOM.VALIDATE_GEOMETRY_WITH_CONTEXT(t.FC_GEOM, 0.05) VALIDATION_RES
FROM ST_SEGMENT t WHERE t.STREET_ID = 'STEID5005';
```

I am getting all (74 rows) `TRUE` validation results, as you can see

[image]

But when I try to calculate length of the geometry object like

```
SELECT t.STREET_ID, SDO_GEOM.SDO_LENGTH(t.FC_GEOM, 0.005, 'KM')
FROM ST_SEGMENT t WHERE t.STREET_ID = 'STEID5005';
```

I am getting these errors

```
ORA-13029: Invalid SRID in the SDO_GEOMETRY object
ORA-06512: at "*****.MD", line 1723
ORA-06512: at "*****.MDERR", line 8
ORA-06512: at "*****.SDO_GEOM", line 2217
ORA-06512: at "*****.SDO_GEOM", line 2149
ORA-06512: at line 1
13029. 00000 -  "Invalid SRID in the SDO_GEOMETRY object"
*Cause:    There is an invalid SDO_SRID in the SDO_GEOMETRY object.
           The specified SRID may be outside the valid SRID range.
*Action:   Verify that the geometries have valid SRIDs.
```

Why am I still getting this error?

Comment: What database version is this ? 
Does this SRID exist in your database ?

Comment: Hi Albert, I checked the version and it is `19` how can I check if SRID exist in the database? as you can see from the submitted image SRID is 82212, isn't this enough? can you please let me know how to check it?

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind I ran this query against database `SELECT CS_NAME FROM MDSYS.CS_SRS WHERE SRID = 82212` and this is returning `UTM Zone 10 (NAD 83)` so I am guessing the SRID is in the database

Comment: You can do `select banner_full from v$version` to get the full version number.

Comment: Can you also show the result of a `select fc_geom from st_segment t where t.street_id = 'STEID5005' and rownum = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised the validation in your example returns `TRUE`, i.e. indicates no error. You should really get the same `13029` error. For example:

```
SQL> select sdo_geom.validate_geometry_with_context(sdo_geometry(3001, 82212, sdo_point_type(4675355.17, 5844284.58, 0), null, null),0.05) as result from dual;

RESULT
------
13029

1 row selected.
```

The reason for the error is that your data is **3D** (`SDO_GTYPE` is `3002` in the example you showed) but the coordinate system is **2D**. See what happens when I compute the length of a 3D line:

```
SQL> select sdo_geom.sdo_length (
  2    sdo_geometry(
  3      3002, 82212, null, 
  4    sdo_elem_info_array(1,2,1), 
  5    sdo_ordinate_array(4675355.17,5844284.58,0, 923377.227,3784105.88,0)
  6  ),
  7    0.005, 'KM'
  8 )
  9  from dual;
select sdo_geom.sdo_length (
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-13029: Invalid SRID in the SDO_GEOMETRY object
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MD", line 1723
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MDERR", line 8
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_GEOM", line 2213
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_GEOM", line 2145
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

If your data is not really 3D (all the Z are or even NULL), then you can do this:

```
select sdo_geom.sdo_length (
  sdo_cs.make_2d (
    sdo_geometry (
      3002, 82212, null, 
      sdo_elem_info_array(1,2,1), 
      sdo_ordinate_array(4675355.17,5844284.58,0, 923377.227,3784105.88,0)
    )
  ),
  0.005, 'unit=KM'
) length
from dual;
```

Notice that the correct way of specifying the unit is `unit=xxx`.

The result is:

```
SQL> select sdo_geom.sdo_length (
  2    sdo_cs.make_2d (
  3      sdo_geometry (
  4        3002, 82212, null, 
  5      sdo_elem_info_array(1,2,1), 
  6      sdo_ordinate_array(4675355.17,5844284.58,0, 923377.227,3784105.88,0)
  7    )
  8  ),
  9    0.005, 'unit=KM'
 10 ) length
 11  from dual;

    LENGTH
----------
4280.38255

1 row selected.
```